# Route all visitors to Codigniter Built Website to specific controller and method

Tags: php, codeigniter, seo

I have a website built on top of codeigniter and I want to take the website down temporarily to make changes. I would like to accomplish this by creating a white-list of approved IP addresses that can access the regular website while I make upgrades, and all other users would be routed to a temporary page. What's a good strategy for dealing with this? Perhaps something using the routing class?

```
    $whitelist = array('99.999.999.999', '555.555.555.555');
if(!in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'], $whitelist))
    $route['(:any)'] = 'maintenance/index/';
```

I also don't want to destroy my search engine indexing, so should I send a specific header to signal that this is a temporary change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are going down the right path with the routes.php changes you are thinking about. The server should use a 503 response code. That will tell search engines you are temporarily down for maintenance and that they should not index the pages.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to do something similar in a MY_Controller extension.

Example in Phil's public controller here:
http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/02/CodeIgniter-Base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY